# How the rise in amplitude of an electromagnetic wave (light) makes the light more bright or intense?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

What is meant by the amplitude of an electromagnetic wave ? I can imagine about the amplitude of a water wave, sound wave but how can i imagine the amplitude of an electromagnetic wave and how can i imagine that increase in amplitude of light  wave will cause more brightness or more intensity ?

Comment: Related/duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408447/how-the-amplitude-of-light-increases-its-brightness

Comment: The strength of the electric and of the magnetic fields.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that an electromagnetic wave consists of electric and magnetic fields that oscillate at any given point in space.

The amplitude of the wave can be expressed more precisely as either the amplitude of the electric or magnetic component of the wave.

Electromagnetic waves carry energy. For light, this corresponds to the brightness. From a biological point of view, the cells in your eyes are excited more by a field of (on average!) larger strength.